# What is the closest free street parking to London city center?

Tags: uk, london, automobiles

If one wanted to park his car for free on the street and visit London's city center, what would be the closest/most accessible place to do so? For the sake of the question, [let's assume that the centre of London is Charing Cross, Westminster](http://www.bbc.co.uk/london/content/articles/2005/08/15/charingcross_feature.shtml).

The parking spot has to be free of any kinds of restrictions (e.g. only free on certain days) and has to be available to non-residents. Obviously parking in Central London itself would never be free, but surely there is free parking somewhere within a 20km radius from the downtown area?

Comment: Where is your starting point? Where is your exact destination - there is no single point that is "London city centre"

Comment: @Peregrine a car rental at one of the airports (probably Luton or Stansted). "London City Center" = West End. Car rental prices are better at airports and if there's free parking it could be more convenient to just get a car at the airport.

Comment: If all you want to do is get from the airport to central London, taking the train / tube is a much better option. Why pay for a hire car just to leave it parked ...

Comment: @Peregrine in some cities there are convenient "park & take the metro" options which are faster than back-tracking to the airport. Besides, I've always wanted to try driving in Central London :)

Comment: Which side ? North, east, west south ? It is going to be a looooooooong search.

Comment: Considering it costs to park most everywhere on the street as a non-resident on weekdays, even as far out as zone three, I think you'll find it very difficult to find somewhere that is free every day (and, even if such a place exists, the likelihood of it being unoccupied is small). You really are best off taking the tube.

Comment: I went through this drill in November, about 8 weeks ago, ferrying visitors in and out during the social season. For starters, when you reckon the congestion charge your notion of 'free' goes out the window. Coming from Stansted there are some great strategies in the area of Tower Hamlets, but you take the good with the bad. Anyway, from Stansted your optimal strategy is a straight shot on the M11 to the municipal car park at Stratford Centre (NOT Stratford International, E15 1XD), £4 for each 2 hours,  walk across the street, and take the Central Line to Oxford Circus.

Comment: Addendum: you can verify the lack of free on-street parking borough by borough, if you're so inclined. For example: http://transact.westminster.gov.uk/docstores/publications_store/parking/parking_zones_map.pdf and https://www.rbkc.gov.uk/pdf/Controlled%20parking%20hours%20live.pdf

Comment: For how long? There is a Tesco car park in Vauxhall that is free but is limited to two hours parking.

Comment: There's free parking near Chafford Hundred train station. That's about as close as you should take your car to London :-(

Comment: You could try one of the websites which allows residents to rent out their driveways or private car parking spaces.

Comment: I would echo the recommendations not to bother driving. Stansted has a great rail link directly into the City, from which you can easily get across to the West End by London Underground (Central or subsurface lines from Liverpool Street depending on which part you're after exactly). Luton is a bit more complex, but still has decent transport connections via a bus followed by Thameslink to useful stations such as King's Cross St. Pancras, Farringdon, and Blackfriars.

Comment: Presumably, there is some part of your planned travel that needs a car. If so, just rent one for that time. A car is a useless nuisance in the London area, so don't rent one for the time you will be in London. You can go to an airport to start and end your car rental, without necessarily flying.

Comment: Depending on direction you might want to look at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13147/where-can-i-find-decent-parking-space-to-the-east-of-london-with-a-quick-tube-co

Comment: I might be able to get you a visitors permit to park on my road in exchange for a beer or two ... although I suppose that doesn't count as "free" :)

Comment: Added a [point to help measure distance from the centre of London](http://www.bbc.co.uk/london/content/articles/2005/08/15/charingcross_feature.shtml).

Answer (score 9):

I know this isn't the answer you are looking for but...

**You would be crazy to attempt to park for free in central London.**

First there is the [congestion charge](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/congestion-charge). This means it is going to cost you eleven pounds to simply bring your car into London, even if you park for free.

Second, while there is free parking in London (but very little), what there is always has very tight restrictions and is incredibly popular. Even if you found free parking, your chances of being able to park there are negligible. 'Unrestricted' free parking, that allows you to park all day for free, would be taken by about 12.02am.

Third, driving in Central London is extremely crowded and not that easy. Unless you have a really good reason, or enjoy being yelled at by other drivers, you should reduce your stress levels and stay out.

Fourth, almost everybody who visits central London wants to move around, and by far the best way to do this is use the underground (or the bus, but mostly underground). If you are going to do that, you may as well park outside the centre and get the underground in.

Finally you are going to say "what about the locals, what secrets do they have about parking in central London?" Well, the locals do have a secret, and the secret is - they use the underground. Even if you live in central London, most people use the underground to get everywhere.

If you absolutely have to bring a car into London because you or a passenger are disabled and can't use public transport, that's an entirely different matter.

Comment: I'm not speaking of driving into Central London. Rather, I'm interested in dropping off the car in Zone 3-4 and taking the tube.

Comment: Which side of London are you coming in from?

Comment: @djna whatever is closest to London city center by public transport is best. Otherwise it could be any airport.

Comment: If you are flying in, then just take the tube a rental car has no value for a tourist in Central London. If you already have a car and are coming into London from elsewhere the direction really matters, driving across or round London to look for a parking space is impractical. There is **no** fun, or convenience driving in Central London, the public transport system works.

Comment: You might want to edit a bit, because you don't really want the closest, you want the most convenient for the tube. I'll delete this answer when the comment conversation stops being relevant.

Comment: How about listing the best options from all 4 sides? That way the question is universal and applicable to all airports. @Kadir already found the best option in the North. I could easily produce such a guide for my city (Prague), so I'm sure Londoners could easily do the same for their side of the pond :)

Comment: The issue is that these parking spaces are ideal for commuters, so many people drive to the edge of tube system and hope to park for free. Hence from 06:30 these spaces are full. So my telling you that West End Road, near Ruislip Gardens station meets your criteria is actually useless to you. Let alone that driving to it from Heathrow is a nightmare of congestion, can easily take an hour for what should be a 20 minute journey.

Answer (score 4):

The closest place you can find parking with NO RESTRICTIONS is [East Finchley](https://www.google.com/maps/place/East+Finchley,+London,+UK/@51.5851276,-0.1665675,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x48761a17d3ef32ed:0x8c8cef12434da8c6!8m2!3d51.58763!4d-0.1642618) on a residential road. From there you can hop on the Northern Line down into central London in roughly 20 minutes.

Comment: But can you actually park there? Round my way (Northwood/Ruislip) any such places are full from about 6:30 AM and remain so all day.